# How to make RegExps ignore some tags

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

I want to make my regular expression ignore if there are any tags between two characters. I thought of getting the child node list and defining some strings that corresponding start and finish tags of that nodes but I couldn't solve how to make my regular expression ignore that tags.

For example, I've listed the insert tags and made this array

```
let tags = ["<div class='cl'>","</div>","<span class='sp'>","</span>"]
```

The string in which I want to search my regular expression

```
let str = "The people <div class='cl'>in StackOverflow <span class='sp'> are very helpful.</span></div>"
```

And I want to find "people in StackOverflow" in this text to get the start and finish indexes. How can I do that?

Comment: In javascript you can get the `textContent` property from any element, it contains the text without html tags.

Comment: Yes, but I will add my result some tags and update HTML of the node. So, textcontent doesn't work in this case. @PoulBak

Comment: I wouldn't use a Regex either. I'd use `.textContent`, `.innerText` or `.innerHTML`.

Answer (score 0):

If the regex matches both the tags and what's not in a tag.
Then you can capture and keep what's not in a tag.

```
/<[^>]+>|([^<>]+)/g
```

```js
const str = "The people <div class='cl'>in StackOverflow <span class='sp'> are very helpful.</span></div>"

let re = /<[^>]+>|([^<>]+)/g;

let result = str.replace(re,'$1');

console.log(result);

let positions = [];
while (m = re.exec(str)) {
  if(m[1]) positions.push([m.index, re.lastIndex])
}
console.log(positions);
```